# Get all rows from three different tables which contain same id

Tags: mysql, select, join

I have four tables.

```
**Users table**     **Books Table**     **Dvds Table**      Toys Table
use_id              boo_id              dvd_id              toy_id
use_name            boo_name            dvd_name            toy_name
                    boo_use_id          dvd_use_id          toy_use_id
```

I need to extract all rows from the three tables; books, dvds and toys which contain the use_id. All i need from each of those rows is the unique ID of the book/dvd/toy.

My SQL is a little rusty but i think i need some kind of join.

Can anyone give me some direction please on my query?

Comment: I do not dig your naming convention. why `use` instead of `user` and `boo` instead of `book`? Making it difficult to read for having 3 digit prefix? And also do not like the namespace when you have a key_pointing to another table like `boo_use_id` - this could be very normally just `user_id` or show the relationship and make it `users_user_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just join them :

```
SELECT u.*,
        b.boo_id,
        d.dvd_id,
        t.toy_id
FROM Users u
JOIN Books b
 ON(u.use_id = b.boo_use_id)
JOIN DVDs d
 ON(u.use_id = d.dvd_use_id)
JOIN Toys t
 ON(u.use_id = t.toy_use_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a `UNION` makes the most sense here:

```
SELECT boo_id, 'book' AS type
FROM books
WHERE boo_use_id = 1
UNION
SELECT dvd_id, 'dvd'
FROM dvds
WHERE dvd_use_id = 1
UNION
SELECT toy_id, 'toy'
FROM toys
WHERE toy_use_id = 1
```